# E: Unable to correct problems....when install wine

Tags: wine

sorry every one... I have a trouble for wine... I reinstall Ubuntu for my computer... when I install wine

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

then Terminal show.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not installable or
                 wine1.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

i tried running

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then i repeated the process again. Still I get the same error.

please help me :'(

thanks for reading...